# Whatsapp .txt file chat into original whatsapp format

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have whatsapp chats in .txt file format. I want it to convert to original whatsapp format (i.e whatsapp original interface). 
**The input is .txt file**

Example:

```
12/11/2014, 12:22 PM - John: Hi Stacy
12/11/2014, 12:22 PM - John: :)
13/11/2014, 2:59 AM - John: How are you?
13/11/2014, 2:59 AM - John: Are u home?
13/11/2014, 8:09 AM - Stacy: Hi John
13/11/2014, 8:10 AM - Stacy: yeah I am good
13/11/2014, 8:10 AM - Stacy: and home too
13/11/2014, 9:14 PM - John: ok
16/11/2014, 4:14 PM - Stacy: how are you?
16/11/2014, 4:16 PM - John: I am good too
16/11/2014, 4:16 PM - John: See u tmrw at work
16/11/2014, 4:16 PM - John: :)
16/11/2014, 4:24 PM - Stacy: yeah ok
```

Now, I want the output in a Word doc with a similar interface as that of whatsapp.

[i.e., all chats by John on left side and by Stacy on right side]

I tried to do that by importing this .txt file into excel and then editing in word. But that didn't work.

**Required output format:**

[Please click here to view the required output word format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYe3E.png)
(Its very similar to whatsapp format)

**This is what I did:**

1) I imported the data in excel from .txt file.

2) I used python code to convert that txt format to excel file
[Please click here to view that file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FPaj.png)

3) I then copied this to .doc file and added borders

4) And now I removed output border. That's how I got the format I attached in the first link.

The problem that I am facing is wherever the text is not there, I need to manually go that cell and select "No Border". I am having 1000's of these.

Is there anyway I can do this programmatically?

Can something be done using Word or Excel VBA?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines in the [help] on how to ask questions here. You need to narrow down your question, show the code you've tried and describe HOW that code did not work.

Comment: @ Cindy Meister : Please see the edit

Comment: Please format it so that it's readable - you want the the help, you do the work...

Comment: I don't think the Java tag fits here. Also, I think you might focus in only one language, because we cannot do the job exactly the way you want it. What exception did you get when running the VBA code? What is failing there? It can be useful that you read the [SO Asking Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Where is the table that you are targeting in your code?

Comment: @ Rahul: stackoverflow is not allowing me to attach more than 2 files because I have <10 reputation it seems. So I didn't attach those files

Comment: see the answer. Add you name or pseudonym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have table as shown in image what you can do is remove the all boarder and run following code.

```
Sub demo1()
With ActiveDocument.Range
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oRow As Row
'remove all boarders before executing this code
    For Each oRow In .Tables(1).Rows
        For Each oCell In oRow.Cells
            If Not oCell.Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
                Set rng = oCell.Range
                With rng
                    With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
                        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
                        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
                        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
                    End With
                    With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
                        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
                        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
                        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
                    End With
                    With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
                        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
                        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
                        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
                    End With
                    With .Borders(wdBorderRight)
                        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
                        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
                        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
                    End With
                End With
            End If
        Next oCell
    Next oRow
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hai Rahul. This is not the exact o/p but I got the idea from ur code and I think I can proceed fwd by using your code.
Thanks a lott :)

Comment: On SO, Many few will be able to understand what you want. You will have to work around the solution they provide.